# Flask redirect to external file and provide filename instead of original

Tags: python, redirect, flask

I use Flask to serve application. Until recently, Flask was serving files for download using response stream.

Because of increased number of worker errors, I now need to redirect request to external location, where files are stores in `7249ed01-9c3d-45fe-895c-5a27db785d2d.tar.gz` filename format. Redirect itself works, but filename displayed in save dialog in browser is still `7249ed01-9c3d-45fe-895c-5a27db785d2d`.

Code example is below.

```py
@app.route("/download/<filename>")
def view_file_download(filename):
    # filename can be ignored, used to retrieve info from db
    url = "https://example.com/7249ed01-9c3d-45fe-895c-5a27db785d2d.tar.gz"
    filename_orig = "example.tar.gz"
    filesize = 123456 
    res = flask.redirect(url, code=303)
    res.headers.set("Location", url)
    res.headers.set("Content-Disposition", "attachment", filename=filename_orig)
    res.headers.set("Content-Length", filesize)

    return res
```

Comment: Well, that's kinda what you told Flask to do in your code. If you're only setting the header don't expect the code to change its behaviour as well. PS: Change the URL :)

Comment: Changing URL is not possible, as this is existing working app with a lot of files. My question is basically to know if this is possible or not. If it is, how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to provide content-disposition header for redirect response.

Major browsers do not support this feature any longer. It is required that server serving files contain content-disposition in own response and it will tell browser to use that instead of hashed filename.